# Prove that: $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n \setminus A_{n-1})$

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory

Let ${(A_n)}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a rising series.

How can I formally prove that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n \setminus A_{n-1})$$

---

Please Note: this is part of more complex claim which I'm trying to prove and I'm stuck exactly at this point.

It's clear for me that this is 100% true but yet don't think that writing this equality should be in such direct way without formal prove.

Comment: This is a telescoping series. I believe you also define $A_0=\emptyset$ for the first term.

Comment: `A \setminus B` produces $A \setminus B$

Comment: @Mark you're correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark mentions, I think you are intended to define $A_0 = \varnothing$.

Hint: It suffices to show $P(A_N) = \sum_{n=1}^N P(A_n \setminus A_{n-1})$.

Hint: Show that the $n$ sets $A_N \setminus A_{N-1}, A_{N-1} \setminus A_{N-2}, \ldots, A_2 \setminus A_1, A_1$ are disjoint and have union equal to $A_N$.

Comment: I was able to prove that: $P(A_N) = \sum_{n=1}^N P(A_n \setminus A_{n-1})$ which proves that $\lim P(A_N) = \lim \sum_{n=1}^N P(A_n \setminus A_{n-1})$ yet I don't see how the right side is equal to what I wrote in my question

Comment: plus is it alway correct that if $A=b$ then I can add $\lim$ to both sides? it doesn't feel correct in all cases since this isn't simple operation like multiplication, subtract etc..

Comment: @zoro **By definition** $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} f(n) = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N f(n)$. It will be extremely unconventional if your definition of infinite series is different, and you should probably mention it. Think back to improper integrals $\int_a^{\infty}$ for example.

Comment: @GarethMa ok thanks, but what about my second comment

Comment: @zoro Do you mean that if $A_n = b_n$ for all $n$, whether you have $\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$? This also holds essentially by definition. One simple way is to see that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (A_n - b_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} 0 = 0$.